# Is the something like "editable snapshots" like forks?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there something like a way to create a snapshot of a database, and then edit this snapshot without needing the full double space of the database? Especially tables that are not edited should not be duplicated.

*Context because this may be a X/Y question:*

I have dozends of really large databases (200GB with thousands of tables) and multiple developers writing software for them, which almost always includes schema changes. Currently there is no way for theese developers to work independent of each other, because for this every developer would need his own version of the database.
However this would require `developers * databases` storage.

In reality most developers only work on one or two databases simultaneously.
It would be OK to copy the databases on demand, because this would only require `databases + developers * mean database size` storge. However to copy a database is to slow. Quick switch is essential here. Also it would be really nice to require even less storage.

So what I dream about is some way to:

- freeze the original database in some way
- then have multiple "shadow" databases that read from the frozen version, and if something is edited (`update`, `delete`, `insert` or schema changes) only the diff is stored somewhere else. It would even be OK to duplicate the entire table, because usually developers only in very small areas of the database.

I've played around with views to the original database, and manually replacing the views in the area I need with actual table copies. However what I really want is a automagically way to do this on demand. Basically a way to duplicate a database really fast and don't need the double storage.

Comment: Even your final output requires each developer to have his own database..let me clarify your ask..a developer gets an initial copy of database and then you want to propogate only changes ..am i right ?

Comment: In theory, you can achieve this by leveraging a differencing disk technology (like VHD, which is built into Windows) combined with SMB shares for the database files. I considered building something like this once, but in the end one giant staging server that copies databases from live periodically was sufficient in practice, even with multiple developers working on it. Unless those gigabytes of data are *absolutely essential* for all developers to get any work done (and it's probably not) SSDT database projects with some sample data are much more convenient (and versionable).

Comment: @TheGameiswar  im not sure what you mean. I don't want to propagate any changes. No new data needs to flow in any direction between the databases. All the changed data only needs to be in the developer database, and the original database will never change.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The DB is edited by proprietary code. And its almost impossible to tell which data the developers actually need. My end goal is to provide small sets of sample data, but to get there, we need a way to work with multiple databases first, so we can start using different databases.